# Internet explorer 9 wrapped in div table, which consist of inputs, select/deselect bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table which consist of inputs in cells

There is strange bug (in IE9, I didn't test it in another IE versions) after moving between inputs (or after select/deselect) table - table's parent div begins to expand if the overflow: auto; property setted and if there is horizontal scroll

How it looks like:

[image]

[Link to sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kg6saffe/1/) try to select some rows in table

HTML:

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="gridwrapper">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                    <th>Column</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='Cell'/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomdiv">
        <label>AddRow</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gridwrapper {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.maindiv {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reproduce this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min-height: 0%; to fix this bug in ie9

```
.gridwrapper {
    min-height: 0%;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this behavior in IE9 when the overflow property is set to auto. However, I can't reproduce the behavior in IE when the property is set to scroll.

Try this:

```
.gridwrapper {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I think in terms of design - it's not the best solution :(